# Length of vector resulting from cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I have the following question. In physics forces are vectors. Now I may write a force as 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F} = F \mathbf{e}_F
\end{equation}
with $F$ denoting the length and $\mathbf{e}_F$ denoting the direction vector. But some forces are the result of a cross product (pseudo vectors). The length is then
\begin{equation}
\vert\mathbf{a}\vert \vert\mathbf{b}\vert \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
with $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ some vectors (maybe position and velocity) and $\theta$ the angle between them. 
However these vectors are also sometimes written in the first form. How can I check whether $F$ in the first form is the length of a cross product, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always choose $|a|, |b|, \theta$, that will give you that vector so...  ...$F$ is always a length of infinite cross products. What are the restrictions? You must pick $a, b$ in a plane orthogonal to $F$!

Comment: okay, but if I consider the length of the cross product, then a change of the sign is possible, but in the other formula a change would necessarily mean a change in the direction, right?

Comment: In the other formula, you can change the sign of $e_F$ by putting a minus before it or you can put a minus directly before $F$. This will change their direction.

Comment: ...or you can swap $|b|$ with $|a|$.